# Структура таблиц в БД для журнала оценок

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mongodb, firebase, связывание-данных

Есть таблица с студентами. У каждого студента есть определенный маркер(оценка) для данного предмета в каком-то дне недели. Тоесть, это обычный журнал с оценками.
Занятие создаётся так: учитель в специальной форме задаёт название занятия и дату. Как организовать связи между таблицами студентов, занятий и оценок?
В результате должно всё выводится как на картинке(я прикрепил). Вывод данных я сделал, но как структурировать эти данные я не знаю.

Ещё посоветуйте книги/видео по БД, в которых описываются разные случаи отношений между таблицами. Буду благодарен.
[image: таблица со студентами]

Comment: 3 таблицы: студенты, предметы и оценки, в последней дата оценки, id-студента, id-предмета, сама-оценка. Если оценки не просто числа, а как то еще классифицируются, то возможно еще таблица возможных оценок с их id и другими нужными параметрами (хоть url картинки как ее отображать в браузере)

Comment: Я думаю, что тег 'Mongodb' здесь лишний

Comment: О, на счёт mongodb. Если с реляционными БД все ясно, то как можно представить все эти данные в виде JS/JSON объекта?